# Is there any refactoring option in IntelliJ to to move a non static member to another class?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

I have two entity classes (A and B) and I want to move one of the members from one A to B. It is a non static member.

Is there an IntelliJ refactoring option that allows this?

I'm using IntelliJ R13 Community Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ 13.1 and below, the refactoring "Move" option only works for **static** members. (thanks, luke)

Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/move-members-dialog.html

Comment: There is a small typo. As mentioned documentation states "Move" option only works for **static** members.

Comment: It's funny how I can't edit the answer because deleting 'non-' is a less than 6 character edit :'D

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the "Extract Delegate" refactoring. Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Higher versions or latest versions of IJ do work for both static and non-static data entry. Try upgrading from your version software. Hope it helps you